# Como ocultar linha da gid com jQuery em checkbox checado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Observem a imagem;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na imagem acima mostra que ao clicar no botão **Exibir não conformidade Não se aplica**  ele oculta os dois checkBox na grid.

Mas o que estou precisando é bem diferente, eu preciso que todos os registros que estejam na grid e que estejam chegados sejam ocultados, e se caso o usuário queira visualizar-los ele clica no botão **Exibir não conformidade Não se aplica** sejam exibidos.

Fiz umas tentativas e não conseguir resolver, e preciso de ajuda.

Essas foram as minhas tentativas;

Javascript;

```
  var validarChebox = $('.dias:checked');
  $("#checkExibirNaoSeAplica").click(function(){

        if($(this).val()=="true"){
            $(".validadorDeChecagem").css("visibility","hidden");
                $(this).val("false");
            }else{
                $(".validadorDeChecagem").css("visibility","visible");
                $(this).val("true");
            }
        });
```

A tabela;

```
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="resultado">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;width:3%;"></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;width:3%;"></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.arquivo"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.naoConformidade"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.chaveRegistro"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.detalhe"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.remessa"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;width:7%;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.naoSeAplica"/></th>
                        <th class="text-left"  style="color:black;"><fmt:message key="label.sagresPessoal.tela.naoConformidadeClasse.observacao"/></th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="conformidade" items="${resultPage.result}">
                        <tr>
                           <td>${conformidade.id}</td>
                            <td class="text-left">
                                <input class="form-check-input dias" name="dias[]" value="${conformidade.id}:${conformidade.observacao}" type="checkbox">
                            </td>
                            <td>${conformidade.arquivo}</td>
                            <td>
                            <a class="modalAjuda">${conformidade.validacao}</a></td>
                            <td>${conformidade.chaveRegistro}</td>
                            <td>${conformidade.detalhe}</td>
                            <td>${conformidade.remessa}</td>
                            <td>
<%--                                <c:if test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo != '' && conformidade.falsoPositivo != NULL  && conformidade.falsoPositivo != 0 }""> --%>
<%--                                  
<%--                                </c:if> --%>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo == '' || conformidade.falsoPositivo == NULL  || conformidade.falsoPositivo == 0 }">
                                        <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);" type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" > 
                                        <br />
                                    </c:when>

                                    <c:when test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo != '' && conformidade.falsoPositivo != NULL  && conformidade.falsoPositivo != 0 }">
                                        <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo validadorDeChecagem" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);"  type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" checked="true">
                                        <br />
                                    </c:when>   

<%--                                    <c:otherwise> --%>
<%--                                       <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo validadorDeChecagem" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);"  type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" checked="true"> --%>
<!--                                        <br /> -->
<%--                                    </c:otherwise> --%>
                                </c:choose>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-center" style="vertical-align: middle;" >
                                <c:if test="${conformidade.observacao == '' || conformidade.observacao == NULL }">

                                    <a onclick="AbrirCadastrarObservacacao(${conformidade.id})">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                    </a> 

                                </c:if>
                                <c:if test="${conformidade.observacao != '' && conformidade.observacao != NULL}">

                                     <a onclick="EditarObservacacao('${conformidade.id}','${conformidade.observacao}')" >
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"  aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                     </a>

                                </c:if>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

A parte que nos interessa;

```
                            <td>
<%--                                <c:if test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo != '' && conformidade.falsoPositivo != NULL  && conformidade.falsoPositivo != 0 }""> --%>
<%--                                  
<%--                                </c:if> --%>
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo == '' || conformidade.falsoPositivo == NULL  || conformidade.falsoPositivo == 0 }">
                                        <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);" type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" > 
                                        <br />
                                    </c:when>

                                    <c:when test="${conformidade.falsoPositivo != '' && conformidade.falsoPositivo != NULL  && conformidade.falsoPositivo != 0 }">
                                        <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo validadorDeChecagem" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);"  type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" checked="true">
                                        <br />
                                    </c:when>   

<%--                                    <c:otherwise> --%>
<%--                                       <input class="form-check-input falsoPositivo validadorDeChecagem" onclick="checarNaoSeAplica(event);"  type="checkbox" value="${conformidade.id}" checked="true"> --%>
<!--                                        <br /> -->
<%--                                    </c:otherwise> --%>
                                </c:choose>
                            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta modificar para algo como o código abaixo, utilizando `$.each()`.

```
$('#checkExibirNaoSeAplica').click(function(){

    var naoAplica = $(this).prop('checked')

    $('.validadorDeChecagem').each(function(){

        var thisChecked = $(this).prop('checked');

        if(naoAplica && thisChecked){
            $(this).parents('tr').css('visibility','hidden');
        } else {
            $(this).parents('tr').css('visibility','visible');
        }

    });

});
```